# CollectionViewSource bind source to webservice (using WCF RIA services and LINQ) - Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, web-services

I have a small problem, probably stupid but I can't figure this out..
Anyways all I'm trying to do is bind my CollectionViewSource.Source to my resulting query in Silverlight 4 with WCF RIA services.

This is my XAML :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvsServiceTypes" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="cvsServiceTypes" DisplayMemberPath="Type" SelectedValuePath="IDServicesType" Margin="154,51,0,0" Name="cbServiceType" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedValue="{Binding fkservicetype, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

And my CodeBehind :

```
  public Services()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      webService.GetServiceTypesCompleted += (s, e) => { cvsServiceTypes.Source = e.Result; };
      webService.GetServiceTypesAsync();
   }
```

But it doesn't seem to work... what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could it be a problem with the DisplayMemberPath being a reserved word? Not too sure myself but that might present a gotcha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you don't mind if I ignore the web service call part - it looks like you're struggling with binding your items to the ComboBox, so that's the part I'll address.

You need to do the following:

1. Create an ObservableCollection property to contain your items.
2. Bind the CollectionViewSource.Source to the ObservableCollection.
3. Bind the ComboBox.ItemsSource to the CollectionViewSource.
4. Set the DataContext on your UserControl.

Here is an example:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Path=Items}"></CollectionViewSource>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=cvs}}" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=cvs}}" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=cvs}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The code:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        _items.Add("a");
        _items.Add("b");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }
}
```

You can put items into the collection when your web service call completes like this:

```
webService.GetServiceTypesCompleted += (s, e) => 
{
    foreach (string s in e.result)
    {
        _items.Add(s);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow but I find it hard to believe that I need to create an ObservableCollection because I can do this :
webService.GetCurrencyCompleted += (s, e) => { cbServiceType.ItemsSource = e.Result; };
And it'll work fine!But I don't want to have to do this with every combobox (because I have some in my datagrids for instance that bind to this source and I can't call those from codebehind) that's why I'm trying to bind it to a collectionviewsource that way, I can bind all my comboboxes to this cvs from Xaml, and I only have to bind it once from codebehind to my cvs.Have I lost you?

Comment: It's bad practice to bind web service results directly to UI items.  The more separation you can put between your UI and web service the more flexible and easier to maintain your program will be.

Comment: OK. I've edited my answer to show how you can use a single CollectionViewSource to populate multiple ComboBoxes - only the XAML has changed.

Comment: Hey Thank you looks pretty interesting! I'll check this out tomorrow! Still, I have an awefull lot of sql tables... I'll have a lot of ObservableCollection to create but if that's what it takes! Why is it considered back practice to bind controls directly to webservice?

Comment: Also can you just show me how I would bind the resulting query from my webservice to my observablecollection?
Thanks a lot for your help btw!

Comment: Separation of concerns (ie your UI does not know about the web service implementation, your web service layer does not know about the database implementation) is the difference between good quality software and poor quality software.  SOC makes it easier to change/maintain your software in the future - this is the most expensive phase of the software lifecycle, so anything we can do now to reduce that future cost is important.  For example, consider what happens when your company wants to upgrade to WCF 5.0 (in many years time)? You don't want to be rebuilding your UI at that point!

Comment: Damn not enough reputation to vote! But thanks a lot! Although I haven't tested it yet I think I'll do the job so I'll mark it as answered! Thanks again for your help!