# Get current selected item in listview

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I display the currently selected item and its price in a message box?

```
<ListView Name="listMenuItems" SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="Transparent" SelectionChanged="listMenuItems_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border  Width="700" Height="80" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2">
                <Border.BitmapEffect>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="Red" Direction="200" Noise=".6" ShadowDepth="10" Opacity=".6"/>
                </Border.BitmapEffect>
                <TextBlock Name="txtItem"  Height="100" Width="650" FontSize="50" Text="{Binding Path=item}"  FontFamily="Georgia"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>    
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>      
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempitem=((YourCustomClass)e.ClickedItem).item;
```

You need to typecast inside your listview Itemclick event then you can access the selected item and price(wasnt able to find its binding in code so assuming).

Comment: i'm begginer in wpf, is it possible to set value field as price in TextBlock ?

Comment: Yes it is possible you would need to create a CollectionViewSource in your XAML

Comment: Create a CollectionView Source in your XAML and in C# you would need to create either a list or an obxervable collection and then you can set it as a source of the two textblocks. Since number of characters I can write is less please go through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465161.aspx & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589017/collectionviewsource-bind-source-to-webservice-using-wcf-ria-services-and-linq